# DEBUG CONSOLE, Is this a bug or is there a trick?

Tags: powershell, debugging, console

I'm using VSCode POWERSHELL,
with these Extensions: Powershell, Powershell Preview,
VSCode Ultimate Snippets.

The Contents of the $Res variable in the DEBUG CONSOLE is obviously not being displayed.
Is this a bug or is there a trick?

Thx in advance Vold

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When using Visual Studio Code's [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell), there is no point in using the DEBUG CONSOLE tab - **use the TERMINAL tab instead**, where the PIC (PowerShell Integrated Console) runs, and where you can interactively evaluate arbitrary expressions when stopped at a break point during debugging.

(When you do use the DEBUG CONSOLE, the result of what you submit actually prints in the TERMINAL tab, surprisingly.)